# Android java.lang.ClassNotFoundException error - Class is there, though

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception

I'm creating an Android app that does a number of things and I've run into this issue that has stumped me for a couple of days. My Google-Fu isn't cutting it and I'm having to resort to asking for help on this one.

I've created a taken a working class from the CyanogenMod Project and begun to implement and modify it. Now, before I started to modify anything, I wanted to make sure it would run properly (as you should). That's when I his this error:

```
03-01 13:45:13.340: E/AndroidRuntime(8394): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-01 13:45:13.340: E/AndroidRuntime(8394): Process: com.ultima.settings, PID: 8394
03-01 13:45:13.340: E/AndroidRuntime(8394): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity     ComponentInfo{com.ultima.settings/com.ultima.settings.SettingsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #142: Error inflating class com.settings.ultima.NumberPickerPreference
```

and later in the log, which I think is of interest:

```
03-01 13:45:13.340: E/AndroidRuntime(8394): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.settings.ultima.NumberPickerPreference" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/app/UltimaControl.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
03-01 13:45:13.340: E/AndroidRuntime(8394):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
03-01 13:45:13.340: E/AndroidRuntime(8394):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
03-01 13:45:13.340: E/AndroidRuntime(8394):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
03-01 13:45:13.340: E/AndroidRuntime(8394):     at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItem(GenericInflater.java:375)
03-01 13:45:13.340: E/AndroidRuntime(8394):     at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItemFromTag(GenericInflater.java:430)
03-01 13:45:13.340: E/AndroidRuntime(8394):     ... 25 more
```

Now, the class is there. It's not dependant on any libraries or anything (that I know of, it uses NumberPicker, which is in the Android v19 source and is included anyway).

I've tried baksmali-ing the apk after compiling it, and sure enough the class is there (smali file).

There are no build errors, and if I remove this:

```
<com.settings.ultima.NumberPickerPreference
        android:key="pref_key_workspaceRows"
        android:title="@string/launcher_title_workspace_rows"
        ultima:min="1"
        ultima:max="10" />
```

from the preferences.xml it no longer force closes, or gives any kind of error.

I'm at a loss as to what could be the issue :(

EDIT:

Here's the [CyanogenMod project](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Launcher3) I've forked and I'm editing.

I'm editing the NumberPreference and the preferences.xml and adding them to my own app (to make room for other things in the settings instead - hard to explain).

Obviously these are the originals, not the ones in my app, but I've made the necessary alterations to the,. Changed the package names, etc.

Comment: Did you see the error in one of your xml files

    Binary XML file line #142: Error

Comment: `com.settings.ultima` in prefeences, `com.ultima.settings` in the exception?  How is the activity referenced in the manifest?

Comment: @Simon It's not an Activity, it extends DialogPreference instead

Comment: @Erik line 142 is the part in the third code block in my original comment. It's absolutely fine, the main error seems to be the bottom part of the logcat, pertaining to the DexPathList

Comment: OK, but something's still missing.  Why the discrepancy in package names?

Comment: @Simon
Oh, wow. Looks like I needed a second pair of eyes on this... I messed up on the package name in the preferences.xml. It should've been com.ultima.settings and as you pointed out, it's com.settings.ultima!

Thanks!

Comment: @Simon
Is there a way I can accept it as an answer or something?

Comment: @Kryten2k35 You should just post the answer yourself so you can accept it; right now the question looks unanswered